# Heap analytics - not seeing custom properties

Tags: analytics

I've implemented Heap analytics successfully and i'm seeing data come in.

The way I set a user is:

```
  window.heap.identify(currentUser.id);
  window.heap.addEventProperties({ platform_type: 'Web' });

  if (currentUser.id) {
    console.log('been here');
    window.heap.addUserProperties({
      'first_name': currentUser.first_name,
      'last_name': currentUser.last_name,
      'type': currentUser.type,
      'country': currentUser.country,
      'company_name': currentUser.company_name,
      'role': currentUser.role,
      'email': currentUser.email
    });
  }
```

I'm seeing the Email property data being recorded and associated (Email was a property already pre-defined by Heap), but i'm not seeing any of the other properties.

So, the `addUserProperties` call is working, but some data is being ignored.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, for me, the custom properties started appearing after a few hours..